# Alternatives to Northwind

Tags: database, sample-data

Well, what alternative sample databases exist that have:

- an un-restrictive license
- loads of sample data
- lots of data types
- a simple mechanism for adding the database to a db server
- are not Northwind

I'm not too fussed what server type (MSSQL, SQLite, MySQL, etc.) the db is designed for.

Comment: This question would also be on-topic at http://opendata.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 7, accepted):

How about

[Chinook Database](http://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/)

See also [Chinook Database Schema](http://chinookdatabase.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chinook_Schema&referringTitle=Home)

Comment: Lot's of good answers, but using a simple sql script to create the db and populate it is the nicest cross platform solution for our environment.

Answer (score 5):

Microsoft do another set of sample databases called AdventureWorks (these are often used in MS courses). They canbe downloaded from here for SQL 2005 http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e719ecf7-9f46-4312-af89-6ad8702e4e6e&displaylang=en#Overview.

I'm not sure how much sample data is shipped with it though!

Answer (score 3):

This looks promising: http://www.databaseanswers.org/data_models/

Answer (score 1):

i love [AdventureWorks](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyID=e719ecf7-9f46-4312-af89-6ad8702e4e6e&displaylang=en), there's also a [diagram](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?familyid=0F6E0BCF-A1B5-4760-8D79-67970F93D5FF&displaylang=en) available

Answer (score 1):

Here are some [MS sample databases](http://www.codeplex.com/MSFTDBProdSamples) from CodePlex, called AdventureWorks.